# Pine throws syntax error on first line of for loop

Tags: syntax-error, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a pine strategy:

```js
//@version=5
strategy("Elie's strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

var float[] overSRLs = na
var IDCounter = 0
int[] removeFromOver = na

for int i = 0 to (array.size(overSRLs) - 1) // line 8
    if low < array.get(overSRLs, i)
        orderID = str.tostring(IDCounter)
        exitID = str.tostring(IDCounter + 1)
        IDCounter += 2
        strategy.order(orderID, strategy.long, 1)
        strategy.exit(exitID, from_entry=orderID, stop = (array.get(overSRLs, i) * (1 - ATR5[1])), limit = (array.get(overSRLs, i) * (1 + ATR5[1]))
        array.push(removeFromOver, i)
```

I know it's not much of a strategy, but I cut out the irrelevant parts to make a smaller reproductible example. When just the code above is saved, it throws the following error:

```
line 8: Syntax error at input 'int'.
```

Now, even though line 8 is the init of the `for`, I think the problem is in the code block *in* the `for`, and the compiler/interpreter just has bad error handling. Is there something I'm missing here? Everything looks fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the problem is in the code block in the for, and the compiler/interpreter just has bad error handling.

Yes, the issue is in the `strategy.exit` -- you need one extra closing bracket in the end there. Compiler does not always provide correct lines for errors in loops. Comment out the loop and move everything one tab to the left and you'll see that the new error is `line 14: Syntax error at input '('.`, which indicates that there is an issue with the opening bracket (because it can't find its pair).

P.S. The script will not compile after that because of the undeclared `ATR5` variable, but I assume it's due to the fact that you trimmed the example code for readability.